# If condition inside for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbie to the `python`. I am sure this is a very basic question, but still I don’t get it in python.

I have two `1D-arrays`, A and B of length 50. 
I want to find for a given user input, A[0], I must return B[0], A[1]——> B[1]  and so forth..

I have created a function to this task.

```
 A = [10, 20,.... 500]
 B = [1, 4,.... 2500]

def func():
    x = input("enter a value from the array A: ") #user input
    for i in range(50):
       if A[i] == x:
          print(B[i])

       else:
          print("do nothing")

func()
```

But if I call the function, I get nothing.
I would appreciate if someone could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You get *no output*? Not even "do nothing"?

Comment: The `input` command is different on Python 2 and 3, so I'm not 100% sure, but I have a feeling you need to convert it to an integer. You're basically doing something like `if 2 == "2"`, which is `False`.

Comment: It would be much better to separate the input from the function, so you would call it as `func(x)`.

Comment: Why is your range declared as 50? Shouldn't you take the size of A?

Comment: Using a dictionary would be a better way: `print((dict(zip(A, B))).get(int(x), None))`. In a real program you would construct the dictionary once and reuse it. If you really want the "do nothing": `print('\n'.join(b if int(x) == a else 'do nothing' for (a, b) in zip(A, B)))`

Comment: yes I got the output "do nothing". As @peter said, it appears I was trying 2 == "2", which is false!! Thanks for pointing out that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
def func():
   x=int(input("enter a value from the array A: "))
   if x in A:
       idx = A.index(x)
       print(B[idx])
   else:
       print("do nothing")
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
  A = [10, 20,.... 500]
  B = [1, 4,.... 2500]

  def func():
     x = int(input("enter a value from the array A: ")) #user input
     for i in range(50):
       if A[i] == x:
         print(B[i])

       else:
        print("do nothing")

  func()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little better, you don't need to use `range()` and will not print a lot of `do anything` it will print `do nothing` if the value wasn't in `A` try this:

```
A = [10, 20,.... 500]
B = [1, 4,.... 2500]

def func():
    x = int(input("enter a value from the array A: ")) #user input
    for i,v in enumerate(A):
        if v == x:
            print(B[i])
            break

    else:
        print("do nothing")

func()
```

read [here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) to learn about `for else`.

Comment: Thanks for the link @mehrdad-pedramfar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A = [10, 20,.... 500]
B = [1, 4,.... 2500]

def func():
    print('A = ' + str(A))
    x = int( input("Enter a value from the array A: ") )
    # enter code here

    # range(min_included, max_NOT_included) -> so range is [0, 1, 2 ... 49]
    for i in range(0, 50):
       if A[i] == x:
          print(B[i])

       else:
          pass  #equals 'do nothing', so you can even remove the 'else'

func()
```